# Alertmanager - which emails were used

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

Is there a way to view which email addresses were used by which alerts?

Want to make sure the alert rules are behaving correctly and sending to the correct email address without having to wait for the respective teams to confirm they received the email

thanks

Comment: There is a web based routing tree utility [here](https://prometheus.io/webtools/alerting/routing-tree-editor/). You can paste your config and check were labelset of your alert will be routed. If it will be helpful, feel free to create an answer yourself.